# Uncaught error. Something went wrong with the query and rendering of this component

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

I am getting this error while adding `pallet_contracts` in my chain. This is my [github-code](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/89c3592fde4c6577962dff6497a0961e0adbd216/runtime/src/lib.rs#L730). Can you please describe me why I am getting this issue?

[image]

**Edit**
As @forgetso suggested in comment, I change polkadotjs apps branch to `v0.132.1`, even after this I get same issue.

[image]

Comment: Try this version for a quick fix `git checkout v0.132.1`

Comment: @forgetso thanks for comment. So I have to clone `polkadotjs` locally then use it?

Comment: I did but got same error I have edited my question above.